# jQuery getJSON not returning json/text file

Tags: jquery, json

I have a webapp running on a local Tomcat server that returns a file "foo" in JSON format.
I have a webpage running on a local Apache server that needs to fetch some data.
For testing, when navigate to

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/foo?function=bar
```

in my browser, it works as intended and I get prompted to download the "foo" file (note that it doesn't have a .json extension and that I cannot(!) change that).

My call looks like this. It never alerts the "success" string.

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/foo/foo?function=bar", function(data) {
    alert("success!");
});
```

When I download the file in my browser, and put it in my local webpage's folder, and use the following call, it does work successfully:

```
$.getJSON("foo", function(data) {
    alert("success!");
});
```

Any help would be most welcome

Comment: Did you check if you're violating [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was a violation of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).